# IllegalStateException when using Curl to verify App Store receipt?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have an in-app purchase for which I want to verify the store receipt. I'd like to verify this from a random machine on the Internet by using Apple's itunes API. The receipt is stored in Parse after the transaction is completed. I'm following the guide on the [Apple developer website](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html). First I get the transaction from Parse:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: [...]" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: [...]" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Transactions/123456789
```

which looks like:

```
{
    "transactionReceipt":{"__type":"Bytes","base64":"asdfqwertyASDFQWERTY="},
    "transactionType":"Purchased",
    "transactionIdentifier":"[...]",
    "transactionDate":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2012-09-10T06:58:44.071Z"},
    "createdAt":"2012-09-10T06:58:37.234Z",
    "updatedAt":"2012-09-10T06:58:37.234Z",
    "objectId":"HyPWJBlWzt"
 }
```

I then take the base64 value inside transactionReceipt and curl it against the Apple endpoint to get the receipt:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
     -X POST 
     -d '{"receipt-data":"asdfqwertyASDFQWERTY="}' \
     https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
```

And all I get back is a not tremendously helpful:

```
{"status":21002, "exception":"java.lang.IllegalStateException"}
```

which I believe corresponds to a "The data in the receipt-data property was malformed.". Getting curl to dump the entire operation with --trace-ascii didn't reveal anything I thought was relevant, I'm sure the issue is not with the connection itself.

Slightly stumped here. It does look like the transaction was found on their end (tweaking a few bytes in the receipt-data throws a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException), so I'm guessing it's got something to do with the transaction itself. Has anybody seen this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I landed here after searching for the same error message. I eventually solved it - the best advice I can give is to double-check that the receipt is valid and that you're posting it to the correct URL. I got your exact error when I was using an invalid receipt (or perhaps just the wrong kind - it was an app receipt, not an in-app-purchase receipt), and a similar error when using a valid sandbox receipt posted to the 'production' verification url.

I was originally using the example receipt data from http://images.worldofapple.com/validating_051110.pdf, after uudecoding it and reencoding it as base64 . I tried posting to:

- https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
- https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

Both gave the same error `{"status":21002, "exception":"java.lang.IllegalStateException"}`. I now suspect the root cause is that this is an app receipt, not an in-app purchase receipt.

I then got another example receipt from https://gist.github.com/sauloarruda/2559455

At https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt I got a similarly useless response:
`{"status":21007}`

Finally at https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt I got the expected response:

`{
"receipt":{"original_purchase_date_pst":"2012-04-30 08:05:55 America/Los_Angeles", "original_transaction_id":"1000000046178817", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1335798355868", "transaction_id":"1000000046178817", "quantity":"1", "product_id":"com.mindmobapp.download", "bvrs":"20120427", "purchase_date_ms":"1335798355868", "purchase_date":"2012-04-30 15:05:55 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date":"2012-04-30 15:05:55 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_pst":"2012-04-30 08:05:55 America/Los_Angeles", "bid":"com.mindmobapp.MindMob", "item_id":"521129812"}, "status":0}`

Comment: The response "21007" is not useless, it tells exactly what was wrong: a sandbox receipt was being sent to the live production environment. That's why the sandbox check worked.